# Setting up a profile and binary for Firefox in Python Selenium won't open a browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

As the title says when i set a profile and binary and then input them into webdriver.Firefox, no browser is open. I have looked for hours and found no ways to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Code I've tried:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary("D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile("D:\\SYC\\fireFox\\Project\\lp5w3va5.PythonBot")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, binary)
```

```
binary = FirefoxBinary("D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile("D:\\SYC\\fireFox\\Project\\lp5w3va5.PythonBot")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary)
```

```
binary = FirefoxBinary("D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile("D:\\SYC\\fireFox\\Project\\lp5w3va5.PythonBot")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="D:\\Python\\geckodriver.exe")
```

Running this code (even with driver.get) will not display any webbrowser. I do not get any errors when compiling this code. I am honestly just stuck on  how I can get this to work,

Doing

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

will start up a browser with a temp profile with no settings (each time I run the script, a different temp profile is created).

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Edit: For clarification, I have geckodriver install in my python folder. Running a web browser with a profile works perfectly fine.

Edit: Solved it. The problem was that putting the profile in my D: drive created a remote dir, but I needed a local dir. Which I had to put my profile with my other profiles in my C: Drive

Comment: does it work when you don't specify a binary?

Comment: Nope. I should also mention that my script will continue to run until it gets a memory error. If I deleted my declaration of profile and binary, then the program runs fine, just having a profile and binary gives me a memory error